# What does 'Quantile Distribution' exactly refer to?

Tags: distributions, biostatistics

I am reading an [article](http://www.genomebiology.com/2015/16/1/117) about normalization of next-generation sequencing (NGS) data (e.g. RNA-seq) where they use the notion of *'quantile distribution'* (page 2). However, being a novice in the realm of statistics, I do not know to what this concept is exactly referring to. Doing searches on the web, the closest hits to this notion I can get are the 'quantile function' and 'Q-Q plot' but still I cannot wrap my head around it.

I would be happy if you enlighten me with your suggestions or possible directions where I can educate myself with this notion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the first lines of [the paper](http://www.genomebiology.com/2015/16/1/117), I understand a "quantile distribution" as a *quantile function* for a probability distribution, that is,
$$Q(u)=F^{-1}(u)$$when $F(\cdot)$ is the cdf of the probability distribution of interest.

In some instances, distributions are directly defined in terms of their *quantile functions* and are called *quantile distributions*. See for instance the so-called $g$-and-$k$ [quantile distributions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02736120), where the quantile functions are expressed as
$$Q(u;A,B,g,k) = A + B\left[1+c\dfrac{1-\exp\{-g\Phi(u)\}}{1+\exp\{-g\Phi(u)\}}\right]\{1+\Phi(u)^2\}^k\Phi(u)$$
with $\Phi(\cdot)$ the Normal cdf and $c$, $A$, $B$, $g$, and $k$ parameters of the distribution. This is a complex distribution as no close form of the density, hence of the likelihood, exists.